# AWS Opsworks - custom chef attribute ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have a new stack name which I handle in /deploy/attributes/rails_stack.rb.

If I try to use it, it fails, and the error stack trace points to a line in the default opsworks rails_stack, not mine.

I see a copies of the original here:
`/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1`

`/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20170401093533_3444-20170401093533/cookbooks/deploy/attributes/rails_stack.rb`

And I see mine here:
`/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2`

`/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20170401093533_3444-20170401093533/merged-cookbooks/deploy/attributes/rails_stack.rb`

`/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20170401093533_3444-20170401093533/site-cookbooks/deploy/attributes/rails_stack.rb`

The docs indicate that it SHOULD use mine.

Why isn't it?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and as much of the detail of your rails_stack.rb as you can